# error when using textbox ,ajax calender extender and compare validator

Tags: asp.net

I used textbox with textchanged event,autopostback true ,ajax calender extender and kepted compare validator for checking date greaterthan today, if i enter  wrong date validation error appears and disappears immediatly and  textbox event is firing ? How to stop event firing & showing error

Comment: please add code here ..

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Dnyan. Please include your code so we can help you.